# batch file will not read the entire csv file i have

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I have a csv file with around 9500 rows and around 60 columns (if opened up in excel). I am trying to have the program read the 1st value in the row and output it to a txt file. Right now I have the code giving me the first and last value it reads:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion


set "input_file=file.csv"

type nul > file2.txt

set "first="
set "last="

for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=," %%i in (!input_file!) do (
    set line="%%i"
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%b in ("!line:,="^,"!") do (
    if not defined first set "first=%%~b"
    set "last=%%~b"
)
)

echo %first% >>file2.txt
echo %last% >>file2.txt
```

I have it to change every , to "," because I have some blank values.
For some reason the last value it reads is actually the 2985th value in the 9500 rows. In reality it is only reading 2984 rows total and then stopping. Is this because of some limitation on the csv file/batch reading abilities or is my code wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: My end goal is to take this csv file, read the 31st column, if it is an O then output the entire line into the txt/csv file, if it is a C then skip it. Essentially I am trying to sort out all of the rows that have an O in the 31st column so that eventually I can send that txt file through email to someone. This is just the beginning because I am a noob at writing code.

EDIT: another edit, the csv file is updated daily and now it only goes down to like row 1040 out of 9500 rows. It seems to change what the last value is everyday.

EDIT: just realized i dont actually have it changing every , to "," it just encircles every new line with "". is changing every , to "," something i should try to figure out or does anyone have another idea?

EDIT: Ok so figured out how to output the lines with an O but the script only reads 203 lines now and outputs the only 4 O's in those 203 lines, like bruhh. Here is the final code that I have:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion


set "input_file=file.csv"

type nul > file2.txt

set "status="

for /f "skip=1 tokens=* delims=," %%i in (!input_file!) do (
    set line=%%i
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=," %%b in ("!line:,=^,!") do (
    set status=%%b
    if "!status!" == "O^" (
    echo !line! >> file2.txt
)
)
)
```

Comment: I would suggest that the problem is on the line following the last line reported. Likely it contains some character that's causing hiccoughs, like `&` or `|`, '>` or `<` or `!` or `%`.  Since you are quoting every comma, what happens if there is a comma within a quoted string? Without seeing that line, we'd be guessing.

Comment: thx for the suggestion, i just did a ctrl+f and there is no comma at all in the entire csv. I will see if the last lines have some sort of character in them thats causing errors, could be that it just happens to be the first line with that type of character. ill keep it updated. thx again!

Comment: Now I've cleaned my glasses and done some testing, your `!line:,="^,"!` simply replaces any comma with `^,`. BUT you say there are no commas, so how is this a `csv` file? AND the `!line:,="^,"!` should not affect the data.

Comment: sorry i meant in the actual data there is no comma. in the csv file itself yes there are commas separating the values.

Comment: Please publish the contents of the lines about where the process stops?

Comment: I don't think I am allowed to post the final line where the process stops as this is a work project and I do not want to accidentally leak any sensitive data. I did realize however that it is the same line that it stops at every time so something is definitely up with that line.

Comment: ok so it seems to be a network issue. the file i am trying to call is on the network and when i copy it into the same folder where the script is, it works perfectly as intended. is there some limitation in reading files over a network or something?

Comment: actually i found something peculiar, i just copy pasted a fresh copy from the network drive into the desktop (where i have the script) and it did not work. it only worked when i opened the csv and saved it again with the same name.

Comment: Odd. Are the files the same size? Try using `fc file1 file2 >diff.txt` to observe differences between two files.

Comment: yea sure enough the original file compared to the saved file gives: Resync Failed.  Files are too different. almost like excel "fixes" the file

Comment: Hmm. likely the original contains unicode and excel coverts to ANSI

Comment: do you think there is a workaround to this or should i try another programming language?

Comment: You could try `'type !input_file!'` in place of `!input_file!`. Other languages? Possibly Powershell?

Comment: dude, that just worked, thank you so much!!! i have it inputting it into a csv so now to try and see what i can work with here. again thank you so much for your help on this issue magoo